# References for finding coordinates in which some natural Hamiltonian becomes separable

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-physics, hamilton-jacobi-equation

Given a natural Hamiltonian,

$$H = \frac{1}{2} g^{\mu \nu}(x) p_{\mu} p_{\nu} + V(x)$$
and a general potential $V(x)$ I want to be able to find the coordinates, given an expression for $V(x)$, such that the Hamiltonian is separable.

I had previously asked a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2340661/separability-of-natural-hamiltonians)  and got an answer, but am more interested in the specific case of a 4D psuedo-Riemannian manifold.

After some extensive google-ing I am coming up empty handed on resources. Can anyone recommend, or even provide an answer?